# Kotlin: App not asking user for permissions

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am creating an Android application that reads a user's SMS messages. I first check whether the user has granted permission for me to read the SMS messages with the if conditional. I have verified that my test phone has not granted access to the app to read the SMS messages, as the print statement is executed. However, the `requestPermissions` method is not triggered (there is no popup asking to **grant permission** to read the SMS messages). I suspect I might be using the wrong permission code or the wrong method to begin with. I have included the following permission in my Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Below is my Kotlin code:

```
// See if the user has not granted permission to read his or her text messages
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    // Request the user to grant permission to read SMS messages
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS), 2);
    System.out.println("Permission Denied")
}
```

Comment: "Below is my Java code:" - FYI, this is Kotlin code!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. It's looks very similar to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) (except they use ContextCompat to check). I would normally check `!= Package Manager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` since that's what you actually want. Why do you believe the method isn't called? Are you sure you haven't already granted the permission?

Comment: You declare `SEND_SMS` in the manifest and `READ_SMS` in your code!

Comment: For kotlin use this lib it saves you a lot of work ;) https://github.com/Fondesa/KPermissions

Comment: Also take permissions are proper in you manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` add READ_SMS
permission.

Use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Instead of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in comments, You have declared `SEND_SMS` permission in `Manifest.xml` file and requesting `READ_SMS` permission dynamically(runtime).

Also it is not recommended to use this permission unless app acts as default messaging app. Please go through documentation [Manifest.permission.READ_SMS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_SMS) which states following

> This is a hard restricted permission which cannot be held by an app
>   until the installer on record whitelists the permission. For more
>   details see
>   [PackageInstaller.SessionParams.setWhitelistedRestrictedPermissions(Set)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.SessionParams.html#setWhitelistedRestrictedPermissions(java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))